# Multiple Button function

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, redirect

I have 2 main interface file there are Admin.aspx and Index.aspx.
these 2 files are connected to 1 same file, is seatbook.js. A javascript file that manipulate data from interaction from Interface. in admin.aspx and Index.aspx has a button "booked" this button that I want to hava multiple function.

When I run from Admin.aspx and click "booked" button then I'll redirect to ForAdmin.aspx file. If I run from Index.aspx then I'll redirect to ForUser.aspx

I took redirect link code on a method on seatbook.js file. this is my following code.

```
  <input type="button" name="submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="ShowArrData()" value="Book Seat" />
```

above is my button code on admin.aspx either index.aspx

```
function ShowArrData() {
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    seatname = o[i].Name;
    console.log(seatname);
    time = jQuery('#timepicker_7').val();
    console.log(time);
    console.log("hallo");      

    var url = "ForAdmin.aspx?noSeat=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&endtime=" + encodeURIComponent(time);                
    window.location.replace(url);
    // alert(url);
}
```

}

(let's forget about looping code. it's nothing) the code above is my method I called when I click button "booked"

```
 var url = "ForAdmin.aspx?noSeat=" + encodeURIComponent(lObjSeat[0].Name) + "&endtime=" + encodeURIComponent(time);                
    window.location.replace(url);
```

that's how I did redirect link. with 2 parameters. I want make it multiple redirect depends on where do you run your program.

Is it possible ?

**UPDATE**:

After first answer I edited my question, to make it clear as like my problem

before showarrdata(), when I click "booked" button, i'll call book_tickes() method, then after that it'll show dialog box then go to showarrdata();

```
function book_tickets() {    
var tickets = jQuery('.seat.selected').length;    
if(tickets==0)
{
    alert('Please select at least one seat to continue...!');
    return false;    
}else
{
    x = jQuery('.seat.selected').toArray();
    jQuery('#seat-form-data').html('');
    jQuery('.seat.selected').each
    (
        function () {
            var ydata = jQuery(this).html();
            xdata = ydata.replace("[class]", "");
            jQuery('#seat-form-data').append(xdata);
        }
    );
    jQuery('#seat-form-data').append('<input type="submit" value="submit">');
    jQuery('#seat-form-data input[type="submit"]:first').trigger('click');       
   $("#dialog").dialog("open");       
}
```

}

then this is dialogbox

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",                
            click: function () {                    
                ShowArrData(lObjSeat);
                $(this).dialog("close");                                       
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}
        }
    ]
});    
$( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

after that showarrdata() method called.

so, there is need some step to process my data before go to showarrdata()(my redirect link code).

Answer (score 0):

By simple set id for button and check the same in your javascript function "ShowArrData()" and do your operation based on this.

```
<input type="button" id="admin" name="submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="ShowArrData(this)" value="Book Seat" />
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
function ShowArrData(e) {
  if(e.attr('id')=="admin")
  {
     //code here for admin page
  }
  else
  {
     / code for index page
  }
}
```

Regards,
Sunil Prabakar C

Comment: what is 'e' parameter means ? before ShowArrData called, it has another method called. it's 2 method called before showdataarr(). how to solve it ? @Sunil

Comment: the parameter "e" nothing but the sender(input button) of the event.  In onclick event i have passed "this" means current sender of the event. onclick="ShowArrData(this)". you have give the "showArrData" as onclick event of button. Then how can you call method before showArrData? Can u explain this scenario or attach code snippet.

Comment: I did edit my code to make it clear as you request. can you please help me to solve it ? @Suni

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation. i got ur point, use global variable for storing current button id.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation. i got ur point, use global variable for storing current button id. And check that global variable for url redirection. For ur convenience u have prepared simple sample in js fiddle. Kindly go throught the following link            http://jsfiddle.net/sunilprabakar/mu2yhbfe/

Comment: I don't understand with your link. I need more detail please.

Comment: ok, i will explain what i have done in that link. I have one global variable 'globarVar' for maintaining button id. I have two button as you have (Admin button, User button). Both button click invoke Book_Tickets method as you have. In Book_Tickets method i have stored the button id in global variable. And in Book_Tickets method open the dialog as you have done. Write the method ShowArrData() which was invoked when dialog 'OK' button click as you have done. In ShowArrData() i have checked which button was click, corresponding button id which was already stored in global variable. continued...

Comment: ..so i have checked the button id in ShowArrData method. For that reason i have used this code  "if(globVar=='admin')" then do the admin operation in showArrData method else do the user operation in showArrData method. I think i clearly explain what i have done.

Comment: Oh I got it. but it still says 'undifine' when I try to console globarVar on book_tickets() method

Comment: could you please check, you set "Id" attribute for both  button.? Bcoz we have checked based on it id only.